# Dub somebody something

Tags: word-usage

In the sentence

> the DRDO-developed anti-satellite system A-SAT successfully destroyed a live satellite in the Low Earth Orbit. With this test, **dubbed as Mission Shakti**, India is only the fourth country after the U.S., Russia and China to have the technology.

**Dub** in this context is generally used as **Dub somebody something**

 He has been dubbed pig.

 But in the sentence above they are using **dub as**. Isn't it wrong?

Comment: Google Books claims over 70,000 written instances of the sequence [*"dubbed the great"*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22dubbed+the+great%22), which obviously proves that ***as*** is not "required". But there are almost 2000 instances of [*"dubbed as the great"*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22dubbed+as+the+great%22), so I don't think we can really say that version is "wrong". It's just far less common, so you should probably avoid using it yourself.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Those numbers aren’t accurate at all. You need to sort by date to get reliable numbers, which leads to exactly [three results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22dubbed%20as%20the%20great%22&tbm=bks&source=lnt&tbs=sbd:1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjlgLnhw6LhAhXyQ98KHXxjAbk4jAEQpwUIIA&biw=431&bih=620&dpr=2) for “dubbed as the great” for example.

Comment: @Laurel I actually get eight results when following your link. I think there might be some element of Google restricting / tailoring the results each of us is seeing.

Comment: @Laurel Also: source on sorting by relevance being unreliable? I don't understand why sorting by date should make a difference.

Comment: @JessSTJ Sorting by relevance includes results that don’t contain the phrase. Idk why, but that’s how it is.

Comment: @Laurel Are you certain though? I don't think you can use the little text previews below the result as evidence, because if you filter by "21st century", it shows only a single result, despite there being 3 of those results (i.e. books written after 2000 and with the phrase directly in the preview) on the first page alone. I think there's something funky going on with how Google indexes book results that mess up the results you get from filtering/sorting.

Comment: @Laurel: Interesting. I knew GB "guesstimates" are often hopelessly inaccurate, but I didn't know  that sorting by date could make such a difference. Curiously, I did actually *think* about doing that myself, because I suspected those "non-standard" instances might be mostly much *older*. I just never followed up on that thought, which apparently has no legs anyway.

Comment: ...whatever - if you search for variants *(**dubbed it/him as** [the]),* there are always *some* written instances. And I still wouldn't write them all off as "incorrect".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't seem to find any source with an official rule on this matter, but I believe either version is grammatically correct. That said, looking at native speaker usage, it seems like "dub" without "as" is much more common. The vast majority of example sentences I've found have the subject coming directly after the verb, sometimes with an article between them, but rarely a preposition. Not to mention it just sounds a little bit off.

"With this test, dubbed Mission Shakti..." sounds more natural (though again, "dubbed as"  is still not wrong).

Comment: Saying Dubbed as is not actually wrong, dub as is but with the suffix it is grammatically correct.

Comment: @Jeef You're right yeah, other commenters have found a decent number of historical examples that I totally missed. I'll amend my answer right now.

Comment: I would consider *dubbed* a synonym of *named*. We would normally say *I named it X,* almost never *I named it **as** X.* In my opinion, *dubbed* should follow the same pattern. While it may not be strictly ungrammatical, I would always drop the *as* if given the choice.